# How do I use spaces in parameters for DBI->connect?

Tags: perl, dbi

I'm trying to connect with an SSL client key using `DBI` and `DBD::Pg`.

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use DBI;

my $dsn = "dbi:Pg:db=mydb;sslmode=require;host=localhost;"
    ."sslcert=C:\\path with\\spaces.crt;"
    ."sslkey=C:\\path with\\spaces.key";

my $dbh = DBI->connect( $dsn, 'username', '' );
```

I get the following error:

```
Can't connect to database: missing "=" after "with\spaces.crt" in connection info string!
```

I have tried using single or double quotes around the values to no avail, and I can't find anything in the documentation.

## Update

With single quotes as follows:

```
my $dsn = "dbi:Pg:db=mydb;sslmode=require;host=localhost;"
    ."sslcert='C:\\path with\\spaces.crt';"
    ."sslkey='C:\\path with\\spaces.key'";
```

I get the following error:

```
failed: FATAL:  connection requires a valid client certificate
```

I know that this configuration works, as it works in Python.

It turns out that this works:

```
my $dsn = "dbi:Pg:db=mydb;sslmode=require;host=localhost;"
    ."sslcert='C:\\\\path with\\\\spaces.crt';"
    ."sslkey='C:\\\\path with\\\\spaces.key'";
```

Why do I need double escaped backslashes?

Comment: @ikegami I do use strict and warnings, and in fact the values are coming from a config file. I just forgot to use double slashes for the SO example. I'll edit, thanks.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show your attempt with single quotes and the exact error message you got for it? There's code in [dbdimp.c](https://metacpan.org/source/TURNSTEP/DBD-Pg-3.5.3/dbdimp.c#L122) in the DBD::Pg distribution that looks like it should handle single-quoted attributes properly, but I have no way to test right now.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Do you mean `"sslcert='C:\\path with\\spaces.crt';"` etc.? As I suspect the OP means `'sslcert=C:\path with\spaces.crt;'`

Comment: @Borodin The code I linked to in my last comment converts a DBI-style connection string to a [libpq-style connection string](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING), converting semi-colons to spaces unless they're in single quotes, among other things. Based on eyeballing the code (can't test right now), I think `"sslcert='C:\\path with\\spaces.crt';"` should work, but `"'sslcert=C:\path with\spaces.crt;'"` or `"sslcert='C:\\path with\\spaces.crt;'"` won't. But the OP didn't specify which one of those he used.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Ah I see he does write *“quotes around the values”* so you may well be right. At least he can try for himself now. Thanks

Comment: @Borodin When constructing the dsn I tried with "$key='$value'" and the equivalent with double quotes. I'll need to check the errors again at work tomorrow (where my Windows PC is).

Comment: "Why do I need double escaped backslashes?" Perl converts `"sslcert='C:\\\\path with\\\\spaces.crt';"` to `"sslcert='C:\\path with\\spaces.crt';"`. And the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING) for libpq say, "Single quotes and backslashes within the value must be escaped with a backslash, i.e., `\'` and ``\\``."

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Ok. It's a shame this isn't handled by DBD::Pg, since it is an implementation detail.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily expect DBD::Pg to do that for you, but it definitely *should* be documented. I'll try to submit a doc patch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To include an attribute containing spaces in your DSN, surround the value with single quotes:

```
my $dsn = q{dbi:Pg:db=mydb;sslmode=require;host=localhost;}
        . q{sslcert='C:\\\path with\\\spaces.crt';}
        . q{sslkey='C:\\\path with\\\spaces.key'};
```

Note that the semicolon used to separate connection attributes must be *outside* the single quotes. Also note that backslashes and single quotes inside attributes must be escaped with backslashes (you have to use three backslashes above since Perl converts `\\` to `\` in single-quoted strings).

If your DSN is enclosed in double quotes, you have to use four backslashes, since Perl interpolates escape sequences like `\n` in double-quoted strings:

```
my $dsn = qq{dbi:Pg:db=mydb;sslmode=require;host=localhost;}
        . qq{sslcert='C:\\\\path with\\\\spaces.crt';}
        . qq{sslkey='C:\\\\path with\\\\spaces.key'};
```

---

As for documentation, I don't see this mentioned in DBD::Pg, but you can see that it's supported by looking at the source. The code that handles the DSN is in [dbdimp.c](https://metacpan.org/source/TURNSTEP/DBD-Pg-3.5.3/dbdimp.c#L122) in the DBD::Pg distribution:

```c
    /* DBD::Pg syntax: 'dbname=dbname;host=host;port=port', 'User', 'Pass' */
    /* libpq syntax: 'dbname=dbname host=host port=port user=uid password=pwd' */

...

    /* Change all semi-colons in dbname to a space, unless single-quoted */
    dest = conn_str;
    while (*dbname != '\0') {
            if (';' == *dbname && !inquote)
                    *dest++ = ' ';
            else {
                    if ('\'' == *dbname)
                            inquote = !inquote;
                    *dest++ = *dbname;
            }
            dbname++;
    }
    *dest = '\0';
```

This converts a DBI-style connection string to a [libpq-style connection string](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING) (libpq is the Postgres C API, which DBD::Pg uses behind the scenes). Since the generated DSN is passed straight to libpq, it needs to follow the rules for quoting and escaping described in the [libpq documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING).

A documentation patch for DBD::Pg would certainly be in order.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the space. It's not clear if it's possible to provide a path with a space in it. If it is, it would be probably be driver-specific syntax. You might have to dig into DBI and/or DBD::Pg to determine the syntax if it's supported. Some have done this and mentioned in the comments that you might be able to use the following:

```
my $dsn = join(';',
   "dbi:Pg:db=mydb",
   "sslmode=require",
   "sslcert='$ssl_cert_qfn'",
   "sslkey='$ssl_key_qfn'",
);
```

Or you could approach the problem from another angle. Windows has a backwards compatibility system to allow applications that only support DOS-style paths. Of note is that DOS didn't allow spaces in paths. By using a DOS-style paths, you can avoid the problem.

```
use Win32 qw( );

my $dsn = join(';',
   "dbi:Pg:db=mydb",
   "sslmode=require",
   "sslcert=".Win32::GetShortPathName($ssl_cert_qfn),
   "sslkey=".Win32::GetShortPathName($ssl_key_qfn),
);
```

Another solution is to use a configuration file as detailed in [DBD::Pg's documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD::Pg).